# Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>' | RXJS multicast

Tags: typescript, rxjs, multicast, subject

I have an Observable that produce the unicast value(individually for all observers). But when i am going to convert into multicast using RxJs multicast operators then it return the following error.

> Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Unicast (Working Code) -

```
let source4$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(4));

source4$.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(`Observer 1: ${val}`);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    source4$.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(`Observer 2: ${val}`);
    }); 
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
    source4$.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(`Observer 3: ${val}`);
    }); 
}, 2000);
```

Multicast(Not Working Code) -

```
let source4$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(4), multicast(new Subject()));

source4$.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(`Observer 1: ${val}`);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    source4$.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(`Observer 2: ${val}`);
    }); 
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
    source4$.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(`Observer 3: ${val}`);
    }); 
}, 2000);

source4$.connect();
```

Comment: I did not test with publish but that will be alternative solution. And why my code is not working

Comment: Actually it seems to work:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPeNOp?editors=1010

Comment: As i see you are also not using publish. You are also using connect.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're actually correct here. The `multicast` operator really returns an instance of `ConnectableObservable` (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/multicast.ts#L54).

This is just an issue with TypeScript types where `pipe()` always returns just `Observable`:(https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L301-L311).

This has been reported and there's an opened issue in RxJS's GitHub page: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2972

The easiest workaround is to force override the returned `Observable`:

```
const source4$ = interval(1000).pipe(...) as ConnectableObservable<number>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go around it by not using the `pipe()` function to connect your operator,
as all it's doing is calling the function returned by `multicast()`.

For example: `observable.pipe(take(5))` is the same as `take(5)(observable)`

The only problem this way is, TypeScript will not be able to infer the type of the Observable. So you will have to specify it when you create your Subject.

```
let source4$ = multicast(new Subject<number>())(interval(1000).pipe(take(4)));

source4$.subscribe(val => {
    console.log(`Observer 1: ${val}`);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    source4$.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(`Observer 2: ${val}`);
    }); 
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
    source4$.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(`Observer 3: ${val}`);
    }); 
}, 2000);

source4$.connect();
```